# Android Texting App change from "Media"

Tags: java, android

I made a texting app for Android. When I tested it I found that if I try to go into silent mode (on a phone) the texting app will still go off, because it is set to a "media" and not a "ringtone" volume type.

Is there any way to change this so when I silence my phone, my app will also be silenced? I don't want the user to have to try and fix it.

**Update:** Sorry for any confusion. This has been a side project I did a while ago and I am just coming back to it now.

The project is a voice to text/ text to voice converter so all commands in the project can be done through voice. The app will "talk" to you through each step of the program. I want to have the ability so silence all "talking" that the app does to you the user if the phone is on silence. Here is how I handle voice feedback:

```
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

public class VoiceFeedback implements SMSFeedback{

  private TextToSpeech tts;
  private String text;

  public VoiceFeedback(TextToSpeech tts, String text){
     this.tts = tts;
     this.text = text;
  }

  public void play(){
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
  }
}
```

I guess the real question I should be asking is:

*Is there a way to tell if the phone is silenced so that I can edit the code to not include voice feedback when there is?*

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the code that plays the sound?

Comment: Yea I will add it once I get back to my laptop. There are a lot of voice commands that get sent back to the user (the whole app is a text-voice voice-text converter) so there is a lot of different pieces of code that are making these calls

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [Ringtone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html) object to play ringtones and alerts. You need to use [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) in order to obtain a Ringtone object, which has a method [setStreamType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html#setStreamType%28int%29) which you can use to play through the appropriate stream.